# Selenium IDE: how to verify that only specific values are present in radComboBox via verifySelectOptions command

Tags: selenium, telerik, selenium-ide, radcombobox

We use `Telerik RadComboBox` to implmement a drop-down list in our web application. Is it possible to use the `Selenium` command `verifySelectOptions` to validate only if specific values are present in the drop-down list?

I'm trying to use it but I get this error message:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js, lineNumber -> 1688, columnNumber -> 20
```

Does anyone have succeeded in using `verifySelectOptions` command to validate a drop-down list with `RadComboBox` control?

PS: my purpose is to validate whether the drop-down list is displayed well as a defined list, not displayed as a non-defined list.

Thank you.

Comment: I have an issue with rcbHoevered. how do you get the drop down to appear and selec the item. I am entering the text with "type', but the drop down doesn;t appear

Answer (score 0):

You are recieving that error because your Selenium IDE doesn't appear to be properly set up.

But onto the issue at hand - `verifySelectOptions` won't work because RadComboBox is not your typical dropdown.

`verifySelectOptions` scans a `<select>` for options, then compares the subsequent `<option>`'s in that select.

The RadComboBox is a custom control, made to look like a combo box, and (from what i've seen so far) is a `<table>`.

*So onto the solution...*
From a quick peak here, i can see that there are a few core fundamentals to the RadComboBox.   First, is that inside the HTML heirarchy, there lies an `<input id="someIDHere...">`

We can use this ID for the Second fundamental.

The second, is that under the `<form>`  which your boxes are under, there is a div with that SAME ID, but instead of ending with `<input id="someIDHere_..._Input">`, it ends with `<div id="SAMEIDHERE_<samestuffhere>_DropDown">`.  So your goal is to find those ID's, then find that list.  Once you have those, you can go to town...

**Using Selenium IDE...**
On your IDE, you can use selectors to simply make sure that the options are there.  For example -
[image]
mind what I said about the ID.

Also if you look at the dropdown itself - that's how you retrieve the ID. (note that itends with _Input instead of _DropDown)

[image]

You cannot read the IDE, so i'll show you the selectors you should have.
`css=div#<THE_ID>_DropDown ul > li[innerHTML='<whatever the text should be>']`
And just verify that those elements are present by using the IDE, `verifyElementPresent`command.

Comment: Thank you for your information.

BTW, do you know how to count li element? as I need know how many list display in drop down list. I try to use storeXpathCount, but always get return 0.

Command: storeXpathCount
Target: //div[@id="ddlStatus_Input"]/ul/li
Value: counter

Comment: <div id="ddlStatus_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Default " style="display: block;...">
<div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; height: 63px;">
<ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
<li class="rcbItem ">New</li>
<li class="rcbHovered ">Open</li>
<li class="rcbItem ">More Info</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>